# Ignore regex separator between "display name"

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split the string with the separator ">," but this separator is allowed between the "" that correspond to the display name e.g:

```
""display>, name>," <email@tegg.com>, "<display,> >" <display_a@email.com>";
```

I need it to be separated like:

```
[["display>, name>," <email@tegg.com>,] ["<display,> >" <display_a@email.com>"]]
```

I'm using at this moment this:

```
aux = Regex.Split(addresses, @"(?<=\>,)");
```

But this doesnt work when the display name has ">,"

E.g str:

```
str = "\"Some name>,\" <example@email.com>, \"<display,> >\" <display_a@email.com>'";
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete syntax for your input strings? While it is of course possible to suggest some regex pattern for the particular string in your question, such a pattern might not match other of your input strings since we (the suggestors) don't have a full understanding of the exact structure your input strings are made of.

Comment: Your input string has some weird quoting, are you sure they are correct?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I added the raw string I'm using in the unit tests that is failing.

Comment: So, this is [what you get now](https://regex101.com/r/W5hDpV/1), what do you expect?

Comment: @PoulBak added the example I'm using in the unit test at the end of the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew To be in a string array like: 
[["display>, name>," <email@tegg.com>,] ["<display,> >" <display_a@email.com>"]]

Comment: That is a list of mailbox mailaddresses defined in rfc5322 (section 3.4). Those definitions tend to be not really well parsable with a regex. You rather should try to find a parser for that. If you already use any library focused on emails there should be one already in there.

Comment: @PoulBak is not a static name like "display" could be anything like "some >, one", "John @#'?!", etc.

Comment: What exactly is the data structure you want to get?  Your presentation of the expected result is ambiguous to me, as it uses a syntax i am not familiar with. It looks like you want to get an array or list with two strings, correct?

Comment: Ok, may be just: `@"(?=""<\w+)"` then?

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/6JU17h, does it help?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Want to get an array of strings separated by ">," outside the "<display name>"

Comment: @Filipe_Silva, i don't understand. How many strings? Your presentation of the expected result suggests two strings. Please clarify.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace it's dynamic, not a fix size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"""([^""]*)""\s*<([^<>]*)>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => new[] { x.Groups[1].Value, x.Groups[2].Value })
    .ToArray();
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/6JU17h):

```cs
var p = @"""([^""]*)""\s*<([^<>]*)>";
var str = "\"Some name>,\" <example@email.com>, \"<display,> >\" <display_a@email.com>'";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, p).Cast<Match>().Select(x => new[] { x.Groups[1].Value, x.Groups[2].Value }).ToArray();
foreach (var pair in matches)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", pair[0],pair[1]);
```

Output:

```
Some name>, : example@email.com
<display,> > : display_a@email.com
```

See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5hDpV/2). Details:

- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a `>` char

Comment: I adapted to my code and it is not working because the "var matches" is str[][]. 
Is it possible to matches be string[]?
Because right now is separating the display name and the address, I want it together in one string

Comment: @Filipe_Silva If you do not need to access parts of matches, just use https://ideone.com/l1yABl.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thanks. I didn't have enough reputation at the time to do it.